# how can i focus to the new element ...By pressing the Tabbutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How Can I focus to the new Element pressing the TAB

```
 var objClass = obj.className;
        $(obj).datepicker({
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true,
            onClose:function()
            {

              $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("visibility", "hidden");
              focusToNextField();         
            }
```

Comment: `$(':focus').next(':input').focus();`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr("tabIndex", "-1")`

```
$('#dateelement').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,

}).next('button.ui-datepicker-trigger')
      .attr("tabIndex", "-1");
```

**[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/x2sqqpoh/2/)**

Observe the cursor moves to the next textbox on hittin TAB button

Comment: i have already tried it ... i am not able to focus to the new element i have many scenario

Comment: I have updated the fiddle..see if this works for you

Comment: Could you say me how can i apply this code for easyui grid?

Comment: Sorry...have never worked with easy ui grid...try posting it as a new question as it is beyond the scope of this question...

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`$('#nextElem").focus();`

Comment: $('#nextElem").focus(); where should i call the id="nextElem" for example i i have a  button how can i call it as element

Comment: function calCalendarDate(obj)
{
 var objClass = obj.className;
 $(obj).datepicker({
     changeMonth:true,
  changeYear:true,
  onClose:function()
  {
   
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("visibility", "hidden");
    focusToNextField();    
  }
   
    });
   $(obj).keydown(function(event) {
//   if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 9) {
//    obj.onchange();
//   }
  if(event.keyCode == 46)
  {
   obj.value = '';
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(":focusable")` to get current element and add focus on next element

```
var objClass = obj.className;
$(obj).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onClose:function() {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("visibility", "hidden");
        var focusables = $(":focusable");   
        var current = focusables.index(this),
        next = focusables.eq(current+1).length ? focusables.eq(current+1) : focusables.eq(0);
        next.focus();
    }

});
```

Comment: its not working i have tried it the focus is going to address bar

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to have a `keydown` event:

```
$(obj).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onClose:function() {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("visibility", "hidden");
        // focusToNextField();       
    }
}).on('keydown', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(e.which === 9){
     $(this).next(':input').focus();
   }
});
```

Comment: function calCalendarDate(obj)
{
 var objClass = obj.className;
 $(obj).datepicker({
     changeMonth:true,
  changeYear:true,
  onClose:function()
  {
   
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("visibility", "hidden");
    focusToNextField();    
  }
   
    });
   $(obj).keydown(function(event) {
//   if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 9) {
//    obj.onchange();
//   }
  if(event.keyCode == 46)
  {
   obj.value = '';
  }
 });